# Banshee 2.9 in Ubuntu 12.04? There must be an easier way than the current answer!

Tags: 12.04, banshee, software-installation

Via the official Banshee ppa in Ubuntu 12.04 it will only get Banshee 2.6.1 but if you installed Banshee in Trusty before Feb. 11, 2014 it would install Banshee 2.9.0.

But the main question is how to get Banshee 2.9 in Ubuntu 12.04.

Most websites say just use the ppa but it only gets 2.6.1, so how do I get 2.9.0 in 12.04?

I'll try installing 2.9.0 in 12.04 using this packaged when I have time: `https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/banshee_2.9.0.orig.tar.xz`

I'll post the dependencies issue's below here so someone could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can build banshee from source. Detailed instructions are [here](http://banshee.fm/download/development/). Make sure that you checkout the tag 2.9.0.

```
git checkout 2.9.0
```